# zsh prints prompt_background_jobs:6: bad math expression: operand expected at `^H-L is not...' after every command

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc, ubuntu-20.04

My zsh terminal prints

```
zsh prints prompt_background_jobs:6: bad math expression: operand expected at `^H-L is not...'
```

after every command.

This is on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine. Also, using oh-my-zsh.

Anybody faced this issue or have fixed it?

Comment: Perhaps you have a function named `prompt_background_jobs` which is invoked via your prompt or precmd?

Comment: Where would this function ideally be?

Comment: I don't know what's your setup is, but you can ask Zsh: `type prompt_bachground_jobs` will tell you where the function has been defined.

Comment: Looks like it's from Powerlevel9k: https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k/blob/758bc175d62a80d944d05277bcd521b61e1459e0/powerlevel9k.zsh-theme#L337

Comment: …which has been discontinued, by the way. You should switch to Powerlevel10k: https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k